# Is it good practice to move common code to base class assuming there is none?

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, code-reuse

I need to print regular report and a batch report. I am using podofo library. I plan to use separate classes for each report but each class will be needing some common functions below (right now in one class in another project).

```
int CPdfBatchReport::CalculateMaxRowsInEmptyPage(void)
{
    int rows = MaxPageHeight / PDF_TABLE_STANDARD_ROW_HEIGHT;

    // because the first will always be the column header in every page, we substrct 1 to account for that
    rows = rows - 1;

    return rows;
}

// Calculates the max rows in current page. The current page is determined 
// by the current x, y position
int CPdfBatchReport::CalculateMaxRowsInCurrentPage(void)
{
    float AvailablePageHeight =  pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - PDF_BOTTOM_MARGIN - y;

    int rows = AvailablePageHeight / PDF_TABLE_STANDARD_ROW_HEIGHT;

    // because the first will always be the column header in every page, we substrct 1 to account for that
    rows = rows - 1;

    return rows;
}


void CPdfBatchReport::StartPage(void)
{
    x = PDF_LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN;
    y = PDF_TOP_MARGIN;
}
```

Does it make sense to create a base class with this common code and do the actual printing in a derived class? Is it a good practice?

So basically I will have the base class say `PrintBase` with the above functions in it and two derived classes from it `PrintBatchReport` and `PrintItemReport` which will actually be using those functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely a good idea to put common code in the base class. "Do not Repeat Yourself" - dry - is a good programming style. Avoid copy-paste programming.

The only time you don't want content in a baseclass is when it's an interface class. But that doesn't appear to be the case in this situation.

Comment: Thanks but I did thought I would make the base interface class as well. Like `print()`method on base class could print either batch report or simple report. By interface class I mean it could have pure virtual and regular functions, why is that not good? It seems like it will do the job fine!

Comment: Right, so there is a difference between a true interface class and a regular base class with virtual functions. A true interface class has no data members and no implemented functions. A base class that can have members and implemented functions. The only time you really should be required to have a true interface class is when a class inherits more than one base (multiple inheritance), at which point having no data members and only non-implemented functions helps make the interface "pure".

Comment: "composition over inheritance", I thought

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, absolutely a good idea to put common code in the base class.

I would like to expand upon @Mats answer. It's really a good idea as far as all the code you extract into the base class follows Single Responsibility principle. Avoid blindly using inheritance for common code extraction. Object Oriented programming is more than that.

Think about responsibilities. In many cases you should favour composition over inheritance. Do you really need any parent class for your task? May be, existing functionality spans several responsibilities and can be split into several classes, which your `PrintBase` could be passed into or instantiate inside.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfectly reasonable solution. In this case, you're inheriting a common implementation so I would strongly suggest private inheritance rather than public. Then you just instantiate the correct child class to do the work. This is certainly a better approach than duplicating code in multiple classes.

Another option is to encapsulate the common parameters/functionality into a third class, and have each of the specific reports have one of those classes by value, delegating the various responsibilities to the helper class.